How to show the same field value from another entity attributes

How can i show the same value of attribute from Item_Stock under entity PurchaseOrder and Warehouse ?
To be more specific, i need to do a calculation from warehouse that when Item_Stock is taken by PurchaseOrder then the Item_Stock value at Warehouse will be minus according to how many total quantity of the Purchase_Quantity.

Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

By using a SQL query, the following should show which products that has the same "item_Stock" value on both PurchaseOrder table or Warehouse table.
select 
  p.product_id, 
  po.item_Stock as PurchaseOrder_item_Stock,
  po.item_Stock as Warehouse_item_Stock,
from product p
join PurchaseOrder po on p.product_id = po.product_id
join Warehouse w on p.product_id = w.product_id
where po.item_Stock = w.item_Stock

the field's value is being shown side by side as different columns for each entity.
